# hide only a view from all recycler view items

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a recycler view item that has few Views. I have a setting that will set the visibility of one Image view after the Recycler view is displayed. What is the best way to achieve this behavior?

[image: in the picture below]

What I tried, in the adapter ViewHolder class, I set a boolean that would hide the element and then call notifysetDataChanged()

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {  
    public ImageView imageView;  
     
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {  
        super(itemView);  
        .....
    }  
    public void bind(item: Model){
        //check and set visibility
        if(showImage) imageview.setVisibility
        else imageview.setVisibility
    }
}
```

Calling this bind function from onBindViewHolder.

Is there any better way to achieve this as all the data remain the same only one visibility is changed?

Answer (score 0):

your `bind` method is fine, but calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` will make your whole list redraw, all items. it's way better for perfomance to redraw only these items which has changed, use then [`notifyItemChanged(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int)). calling it will make only single `onBindViewHolder` call with desired `position`, thus only one desired item will be redrawn (your `bind` call)

note there are more methods for preventing whole list redraw:

```
notifyItemChanged(int)
notifyItemInserted(int)
notifyItemRemoved(int)
notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)
```

Comment: I want to hide the view from all the items,  not just some item or range.

Comment: so `notifyDataSetChanged()` is sufficient for you, and `bind` method (and way of using it) is fine. (still, for preventing warning in Android studio you may use `notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount()-1)`

Answer (score -1):

Are you try this?

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).